# How to get curent's page URL when using datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am doing the following to pass date parameters of the datepicker using AJAX and it works perfect. However along with the date, I also need to pass my current page *URL*.

That does not work. In fact, I have tried passing simple values too (along with date) but only date seems to be passing here.

Example:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
    inline: true,
    showOtherMonths: false,
    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    onSelect : function(d,i) {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
        pageurl = document.URL,
        dayGet  = date.getDate(),  
        monthGet = date.getMonth(),              
        yearGet =  date.getFullYear();
        $(".right-content").html('');
        $.post('date-change.php', {dayPost: dayGet, monthPost: monthGet, yearPost: yearGet, theurl: pageurl} , function(data) {
                         $(".right-content").html(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: All POST params are correctly sent to your PHP file, how does your data-change look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append date to the URL try using:

```
onSelect : function(d,i) {
       pageurl = 'http://mysite/events/default.php?dt=' + d;
}
```

To get your current URL use:

```
window.location.href
```

or

```
window.location.host
```

> Use `window.location` for read and
>   write access to the [location
>   object](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location#Location_object)
>   associated with the current frame. If
>   you just want to get the address as a
>   read-only string, you may use
>   `document.URL`, which should contain
>   the same value as
>   `window.location.href`.